# unable to find vcvarsall,bat error while installing simplecv on windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, simplecv

During the installation phase, I get this, "Unable to find vcvarsall.bat" error. The installation process did complete, though. However, I was unable to see the shell on my desktop (I am using windows) and neither was I able to open it manually. I scoured the internet for the error but was unable to find any solution for this case.

The installation process is through a superpack that downloads Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleCV is not receiving much love in the past few years, and most of it's code don't got upgrade like the libraries it depends on.

The problem you got is the Superpack trying to compile an older version of OpenCV.

When running the Superpack, you should have seen and redtext error, and if you try to run a code it should show you something like this:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\SimpleCV\base.py", line 59, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Cannot load OpenCV library which is required by SimpleCV")
ImportError: Cannot load OpenCV library which is required by SimpleCV
```

There are a few paths you can try from there:

**1. You can try to install [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)**

Uninstall everything SuperPack installed in your PC or it may not work

It may fixes some other uses when using `pip`.
Now you have to install SimpleCV again.

**2. Try to install OpenCV(2.3) on your own:**

You can use `pip` for it, just remember to chose 32bits to keep compatibility with (Super Pack)

Just run on CMD
`pip install OpenCV` or `python -m pip install OpenCV`

**3. Give up on SuperPack and install everything on your own.**

You can try this guide
https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV#windows-7vista

Or use `pip` for all dependencies

```
numpy (Numpy+MKL make sure to install this one first)
scipy
PIL
ipython
svgwrite
pygame==1.9.1release
OpenCV
```

You can find a useful list of wheels here
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

Sources:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/
- http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv
- https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV#windows-7vista